# Best Practice - Customise a WooCommerce+Wordpress Templates

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, page-template, customization

To integrate customise HTML/CSS to Wordpress without editing default ready theme template from Wordpress

1. Download HTML5Blank Boiler plate
2. modify/overide boilerplate css with our customise Css
3. Create custom Template / Post templates
4. Install ACF Modify header.php

My question is, as a web developer, if I wanted to customise WooCommerce template / styling /layout ? Usually which best practices I should go for ?

1. Can we modify WooCommerce template as this [link](http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-custom-templates-tips-and-best-practices/)'s presentation does?
2. Or I should [download WooCommerce ready template](https://colorlib.com/wp/free-woocommerce-wordpress-themes/) and modify from the ready templates?

Is my first time to build WooCommerce site,this site will includes of :

- Wordpress CMS to update / modify content
- Woocommerce to track order /
  add product

May I know which development method / best practice is for web developer to develop WooCommerce + Wordpress site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice for editing a Woocommerce theme is similar to Wordpress as you should use `Hooks` and `Filters` when possible.
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

But if you do need to edit a template Woocommerce outlines this on their website as well: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

You just need to make the template upgrade safe by copying the template to your theme in to a woocommerce folder.